# awk syntax in Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, awk, syntax

I'm trying to port an unix script on windows, and i'm struggling on a `awk` command. Here it is:

`awk 'BEGIN { func=""; } /FUnction/ { func=$2 } /Lines/ { if (func != "") { printf func";"$2 }; func = ""; }'`

I've read some topic here and ther and found out that Windows have problems with quotes. So i corrected it like that:

`awk "BEGIN { func=\""\""; } /Function/ { func=$2 } /Lines/ { if (func != \""\"") { printf func\"";\""$2 }; func = \""\""; }"`

But i still got this error:

```
awk: BEGIN { func=""; } /Function/ { func=$2 } /Lines/ { if (func != ""){ print func";"$2 }; func = "";}  
             ^syntax error           ^syntax error           ^syntax error                   ^syntax error
```

(note that there is no error on the `print func`)

Some people said that it should be better to put the awk code in a separate script and call it, but this awk command is already in a script calling some others scripts...i would like to reduce the numbers of scripts. 
EDIT: finally understand what's the given file and what should this awk command do! Here it is:

The given file is like that:

```
Function 'FunctionName'
Lines executed: X% of Y

\\Later on, i have this: 
File 'FileName'
Lines executed: X% of Y
Creating 'FileName.gcov'
```

The `awk`command is supposed to find the word `Function`, take what is after it (so the function name), then found the word `Lines`, take what is after it, and gives it back this way:

```
FunctionName;executed:%X of Y
```

then i got sed command to suppress the `executed:` part. (\o/)

so, made some thought about it: why is it suppose to work better when in a separate script, and why it seems to dislike every character in my brackets? So i've tried this thing:

`awk " \" BEGIN { func=\""\""; } /Function/ { func=$2 } /Lines/ { if (func != \""\"") { printf func\"";\""$2 }; func = \""\""; }\" "`

It is working... more or less. Well, i don't have syntax error anymore and it does gives me an output file, but it's not what i was looking for. 
What i got looks like that:

```
Function 'FunctionName'
Function 'FunctionName'
Lines executed: X% of Y
Lines executed: X% of Y
\\same for each function; dunno why the lines are doubled
\\Later on, i have this: 
File 'FileName'
File 'FileName'
Lines executed: X% of Y
Lines executed: X% of Y
Creating 'FileName.gcov'
Creating 'FileName.gcov'
```

So it's just repeating each line of the input file. No idea why.

So, now that i understand what it takes and what it's supposed to do, i'll be more able to find a solution, but still open to any tip!

Comment: Have a look at this https://superuser.com/questions/524822/awk-equivalent-functionality-on-windows it looks as though it may clear up some syntax confusion.

Comment: My understanding is that in Windows scripts have to be enclosed in double quotes, not single. I've never used awk in Windows other than through cygwin and the advice I always see/give is to put the awk script in a file to avoid Windows nightmarish quoting rules but you could try `awk "BEGIN{func=\"\"} /Function/{func=\$2} /Lines/{ if (func != \"\") { printf \"%s;%s\", func, \$2 } func=\"\" }"`. I recommend you try to get some small script like `awk '/Function/{print "func="$2}'` working first and then tackle your bigger script. You never need sed when you're using awk btw.

Comment: `$2` is the 2nd space-separated field on the current line btw, not the 2nd line in the file.

Comment: @ZachPedigo: i've sawn this topic already, but it's not helping: they search a native windows command to do the same as awk. I search how to use awk on windows. 
@EdMorton: the second script you gave is working, giving this result àt the end: `func = FunctionNameX` (each line a new one). But the first one got the same syntax error problem, and does not accept the backslash before $2 (i don't think $ is a character who need to be escaped, is it?)

Comment: If i put it in a script, i'll have to make one script per `awk` i want to perform, or can i make a script containing multiple awk command with targets?
@EdMorton forgot to say that you need to double % ;)

Comment: Again, I don't know Windows quoting rules at all, I was just throwing out a couple of guesses to see if they'd help. If you have a small script that works, add something to and make that work, then something else etc. Don't just say the small one works but the large one doesn't and give up - keep working on it. Sorry, idk what that last part about making one script per awk means.

Comment: @EdMorton: of course i'm still working on it, just the way you said. Was just giving you feedback here. To the last part: i have more than one awk command in my script. The one here is just the first one. So i can put it in another script and call it, but will i have to make another separate script for the next awk command, or can i put them all in one?

Comment: Yes, each script goes in a separate file.

Answer (score 1):

So, i found out the problem, and it was a weird one:

Apparently, you can't use the words `func` or `function` as a variable name.

That's it.

So, i've just changed the variable name, and it works perfectly -_-

```
awk " BEGIN {f=\"\" } /Function/ { f=$2 } /Lines/ { if (f!= \"\"){ print f\";\"$3 } f= \"\"} "
```

(note: for my particular problem, i also had to change $2 to $3, but this is because the input file does not really have the same format. nothing to do with awk)